# Windows ADFS User Certificate URL

Tags: adfs, single-sign-on, saml

I have setup a window lab server based on windows server 2012 r2. I have an AD, ADFS and CS.

I have setup User certificate enrollment. Everything work fine but I have a litle issue.

I have setup ADFS SAML2 authentication and some of my server use it has SSO.
All URLs are: myserver1.mylab.lab, myserver2.mylab.lab, myserver3.mylab.lab

myserver1.mylab.lab is my ADFS server when I go on myserver2/3.mylab.lab I'm redirected to myserver1.mylab.lab set the authentication and be redirected to the requested server.

The problem is when I accessing myserver2/3.mylab.lab the web client (chrome/IE) propose the user certificate for authentication click on ok or cancel I'm redirected to adfs server the user certificate appear and I'm redirect to the initial server.

So my question is: can I generate the user certificate only for myserver1.mylab.lab ? As I use SAML2 authentication so I have every redirection implemented and everything work correctly?